# What is the Jacobian's form of a discretized PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-optimization, newton-raphson, parabolic-pde

I need to solve a PDE using finite difference method with the Newton-Raphson Method. In the merhod, I need to calculate the Jacobian matrix of the residual of the discretised PDE.

The PDE may be like:

$$ K\frac{\partial{C}}{\partial{t}} 
- \nabla\cdot(\lambda\nabla{C}) = q.
$$

So the residual $R$ of one time step ($\Delta t$) is

$$
R = K (\partial{C}) - \nabla\cdot(\lambda\nabla{C})\Delta t - q\Delta t
$$

Then I need to write the Jacobian of the residual (wrt. $C$; i.e., $\frac{\partial{R}}{\partial{C}}$) for minimizing the residual and finding the solution. Could anyone tell me that what is the discretized form of $\frac{\partial{R}}{\partial{C}}$? A two dimensional spatial discretization (x, y) is OK. Thank you.

Comment: Why would you want to use Newton's method to deal with a linear pde? You end up solving a linear problem anyway.

Comment: @PierreCarre To consider larger time step and accuracy using impicit form discretization, I am trying to use Newton iterration method. Before this, I had tested using direct solver; however, I encoutered problem when varing to large time step.